# ClassNotFound Exception for jdbc "uncanaccess" path setting for MS Access

Tags: java, jdbc, ucanaccess

I am writing a very simple code to connect MS Access database to my java program using netBeans. 
The driver ucanaccess and MS access file is placed in the very same folder. Kindly guide me through it.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Connection c = null;
    Statement s = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try{
         Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
    c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://First1.accdb");
    s = c.createStatement();
    s.executeUpdate("insert into std values(5, 'junaid')");
    //set classpath=.c:./*;
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
```

Comment: The name of the driver, according to the documentation, is `net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver`. With a capital U.

Comment: Yes I have corrected it to capital 'U', still facing the same error. @RealSkeptic

Comment: The documentation also says you have to give full path of the file, including drive letter.

Comment: Okay now I have given the full path, still the same error.

Comment: Edit your question and show your updated code.

Comment: Have you added the JAR files for UCanAccess *and its dependencies* (HSQLDB, Jackcess, etc.) as "Libraries" in your NetBeans project? For details, look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21955257/2144390).

Comment: Bundle of thanks @Gord Thompson. I have found the answer I was looking for. :)